# How to replace html in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've been reading for hours and can't figure out how to do this. I can find examples of everything but what I need. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

I have a wordpress site where I need to change this

```
<div style="margin-top:-501px;margin-left:6px;">
```

to this

```
<div class="flex-video">
```

in every post. There must be something I can add to the single.php file to accomplish this.

Comment: you are looking for `str_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Thanks, I just haven't been able to find a good example that makes sense to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want database way

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var cntnt = jQuery("body").html();
if(cntnt.indexOf('style="margin-top:-501px') > -1)
  {
var cntntreplaced = cntnt.replace(/<div style="margin-top:-501px;margin-left:6px;">/gi,'<div class="flex-video">');
$( "body" ).replaceWith( "<body>"+cntntreplaced+"</body>" );
}
 });
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Now I just have to figure out why it deleted my background color lol

Comment: The edit doesn't work at all. I'm looking at the first code but can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: It was a variablename mistake in edit have a look now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this markup is inside of the `wp_posts` table, why would you have `single.php` manipulate this after the fact? You can just fix the source in a big batch. Run this query:

```
UPDATE 
    wp_posts
SET
    post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'style="margin-top:-501px;margin-left:6px;"', 'class="flex-video"');
WHERE
    post_content LIKE '%style="margin-top:-501px;margin-left:6px;"%'
```

Note the `WHERE` part may not be necessary, but if you have a large number of posts, the query will execute much faster, so it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I wish I could just do that. I should of went into more details why I need another solution. The thing is that I'm using a different theme for a mobile version and the original markup needs to stay the same for the main site, so I can't just change the posts. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @Brett On your main site's stylesheet, add `.flex-video { margin-top: -501px; margin-left: 6px; }`... you can throw `!important` after both of those CSS attributes if you need to force them that way too